# How do I get the p value of AD test using the results of scipy.stats.anderson()

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, p-value, scipy

I am conducting an Anderson Darling test for normality using `scipy.stats.anderson()` command in python. I am getting test statistic, critical values at various significance levels as the output.

The thing is I have to report $p$ values. Is there a way to compute $p$ value from the given outputs?

Comment: You should consider using `statsmodels` library --- namely the following function [statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.normal_ad](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.normal_ad.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://www.spcforexcel.com/knowledge/basic-statistics/anderson-darling-test-for-normality  for a explanation for the actual statistics. Python code for calculating P value is below.

```
import scipy.stats as si
import math
import pandas as pd


x = 2
length = 50
PDdata = pd.read_csv("data/Bmax50.csv")
data = PDdata.to_numpy()
print("Values = ", data[0:length, x])
AD, crit, sig = si.anderson(data[0:length, x], dist='norm')
print("Significance Levels:", sig)
print("Critical Values:", crit)
print("\nA^2 = ", AD)
AD = AD*(1 + (.75/50) + 2.25/(50**2))
print("Adjusted A^2 = ", AD)
if AD >= .6:
    p = math.exp(1.2937 - 5.709*AD - .0186*(AD**2))
elif AD >=.34:
    p = math.exp(.9177 - 4.279*AD - 1.38*(AD**2))
elif AD >.2:
    p = 1 - math.exp(-8.318 + 42.796*AD - 59.938*(AD**2))
else:
    p = 1 - math.exp(-13.436 + 101.14*AD - 223.73*(AD**2))
print("p = ", p)
```

Comment: Is the above only valid for calculating p-values for a normal distribution or can it be correctly applied to other continuous distributions as well such as Weibull, Exponential, etc.?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564958/calculating-p-values-for-anderson-darling-test-for-non-normal-distributions